# awk: manipulations with multi-column data

Tags: awk

The following AWK script (being a part of the bash code) extracts numbers from selected columns of input.csv as well as do some simple stat operations of these numbers, eventually saving the results as 1 line in output.csv:

```
awk -F ", *" '                  # set field separator to comma, followed by 0 or more whitespaces
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      var = s2 / n - m * m      # variance
      if (var < 0) var = 0      # avoid an exception due to round-off error
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min      # lowest dG
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in cluster with highest pop
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3 (assuming all $3 < 0)
   max = 0                      # highest value of $2 (assuming all $2 > 0)
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
   if ($2 > max) {
      max = $2                  # update popMAX
      fourth = $3               # update the value of dG corresponded to topPOP
   }
}
END {
  if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
   m = s / n
   var = s2 / n - m * m
   if (var < 0) var = 0
   mean[suffix] = m
   rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
   lowest[suffix] = min     # most negative dG
   highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in a cluster with pop(MAX)
  }
   print "Lig(CNE)", "dG(min)", "dG(popMAX)", "dG(mean)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s %.2f %.2f %.2f\n", i, lowest[i],  highest[i], mean[i]
}'  input.csv > output.csv
```

While operating with input.csv (shown below), it extracts numbers from the third column (dG) of the log: i) detecting the minimal value in the third column (dG(min) which always corresponds to the line with ID=1), as well as the number of the dG corresponded to the maximal number in the second column (POPmax):

```
# input.csv from the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # this is dG min to be extracted
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200 # this is dG corresponded to pop(MAX) to be extracted
```

finally it saves the results in another multi-column output.csv file, contained a part of the name of each processed CSV (with corresponded prefix used as the ID of the line), as well as information regarding its dG(min), dG(popMAX) as well as mean value calculated for all numbers in 3rd (dG) column:

```
# output.csv
Lig(CNE)    dG(min) dG(popMAX) dG(mean)
lig12       -5.65   -4.12     −5.055
```

So dG(min) is the number of $2 (dG) from the line with ID=1 of input.csv (lowest dG) and dG(popMAX) correspond to the value dG detected in the line, which has highest value in $2 (POP)

I need to modify the AWK part of my script adding two additional columns to the output.csv with the information regarding 2nd column of input.csv (POP) for each of the corresponded dG value (the has been taken from the 3rd column of the same log). So the same log should be like this

```
# output.csv
Lig(CNE).   dG(min) POP(min)    dG(popMAX) POP(max) dG(mean)
lig12       -5.65   (142)       -4.12      (150)    −5.055
```

In other worlds, additionally to the operations performed on the 3rd column, I need to consider the numbers from the 2nd column and then match both of them in the output.csv: so the POP(min) should be taken from the $2 of the first line (with dG(min) ) and POP(max) from $2 of the line with dG(popMAX).

I have tried to define a 2nd column infiormation using

```
'{print $2}'
```

but the resulted output.csv did not match the order of the lines of the original input.csv (for instance it took the 2nd column from the line not belonged to dG(min) etc)

Comment: You do realize that the `for (i in mean)` loop traverses the associative array in an order different than it was created?

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much for your kind comment, I've just edited the AWK code, Actually I forgot to add there a part of AWK script which computes also mean for dG column and store the value in the array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try:

```
awk -F ", *" '                  # set field separator to comma, followed by 0 or more whitespaces
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
      m = s / n                 # mean
      var = s2 / n - m * m      # variance
      if (var < 0) var = 0      # avoid an exception due to round-off error
      mean[suffix] = m          # store the mean in an array
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min      # lowest dG
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in cluster with highest pop
      pop_min[suffix] = popmin  # pop in cluster with lowest dG
      pop_max[suffix] = max     # highest pop
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s = 0                        # sum of $3
   s2 = 0                       # sum of $3 ** 2
   n = 0                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3 (assuming all $3 < 0)
   max = 0                      # highest value of $2 (assuming all $2 > 0)
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) {
      min = $3                  # update the lowest value
      popmin = $2               # newly introduced variable
   }
   if ($2 > max) {
      max = $2                  # update popMAX
      fourth = $3               # update the value of dG corresponded to topPOP
   }
}
END {
   if (n) {                     # just to avoid division by zero
      m = s / n
      var = s2 / n - m * m
      if (var < 0) var = 0
      mean[suffix] = m
      rmsd[suffix] = sqrt(var)
      lowest[suffix] = min      # most negative dG
      highest[suffix] = fourth  # dG in a cluster with pop(MAX)
      pop_min[suffix] = popmin  # pop in cluster with lowest dG
      pop_max[suffix] = max     # highest pop
   }
      print "Lig(CNE)", "dG(min)", "POP(dGmin)", "dG(popMAX)", "POP(max)", "dG(mean)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s %.2f (%d) %.2f (%d) %.2f\n", i, lowest[i], pop_min[i], highest[i], pop_max[i], mean[i]
}' input.csv
```

- The highest pop associated with `dG(popMAX)` is already assigned to
  the existing variable `max`.
- The variable `popmin` has been introduced to hold the pop value
  associated with the lowest dG. The variable is updated whenever `min`
  (the lowest dG) is updated.

BTW the variable names such as `min` or `max` are getting less
self-explanatory due to the repeated extensions. It may be better to
rename them and/or refactor the code for future maintainability.

Comment: It works very well! And yes indeed the problem was due to the variables and loopin through the mean array at the end ... MANY THANKS !!

Comment: just one question in order that I could test script with thousands of csvs. Assuming that we already now pop_max[suffix] and its corresponded d(G), defined as highest[suffix]. How I can define additionally as a separate value (and print it in the output) the ID of this line, usually located in input.csv in the 1st column (in that example it is ID=4)? Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: I suppose you have already known how to do that. Otherwise you will need to repeat asking whenever you want to modify the script. Please try for yourself and good luck!

Comment: If you encounter a problem after you try, please feel free to ask again.

Comment: like via introducin a new variable id[suffix] = id, id = $1 or it should be updated each time along with the others variables ?

Comment: Try it first, see the difference, then consider why. You have nothing to lose anyway. (Instead you' ll gain your knowledge and experience.)

Comment: actually I have got at the output again mismatch between the lines as It had been in the case of POP column ... so seriously this number of IF conditions put me into the stuck

Comment: If you are asking a question, please provide your code, the problem, and your expected result, not in comments. BR.

Comment: OK! this is the question directly related to printing of the first column + some math operations on the second and thirds column in the same csv files used my bash workflow that I had demonstrated previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67489194/awk-math-operations-of-multi-column-data-in-multiple-csv-files

Comment: Thank you for posting your question, but I'm very confused right now.
In the previous tasks, we were extracting some specific values (max, min, mean, etc.) as a representative values for the file across records.
For instance, `dG(min)` and `dG(popMAX)` come from different records
and their IDs are unrelated.
However you have suddenly introduced the ID-based operation and your
example tells us to calculate something by record. Is this a
totally different task? I am absolutely at a loss about your final goal and
approach. If karafka's post is answering your question, everything is okay.

Comment: Thank you for your comment ! Indeed this is another task where I need to process line by line of the csv and reduce number of the columns via applying of some math equation on each value of $2 and $3 (on each line) . I am going to finish testing the awk solution that has been proposed and probably will create a new topic since there is some issue between awk and bash ( since actually the algorithm should be applied on many csv s located in different folders and in the final output I need to merge all processed files with the indication of the name of the original folder contained input.CSV )

Comment: just made a new topic demonstrating my bash/AWK workflow which required some more modifications: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501145/awk-sed-post-processing-of-multi-column-filles