# awk: math operations of multi-column data in multiple CSV files

Tags: bash, math, awk

I am working on bash script that loops multi-column data filles and executes integrated AWK code to operate with the multi-column data.

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results
    

while read -r d; do
awk -F ", *" '                  # set field separator to comma, followed by 0 or more whitespaces
FNR==1 {
   if (n) {                     # calculate the results of previous file
     f=                   # apply this equation to rescore data using values of $3 and $2
      f[suffix] = f          # store the results in the array
      n=$1 # take ID of the column
   }
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   n = 1                        # count of samples
   min = 0                      # lowest value of $3 (assuming all $3 < 0)
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   s2 += $3 * $3
   ++n
   if ($3 < min) min = $3       # update the lowest value
}
   print "ID" prefix, rescoring
   for (i in n)
      printf "%s %.2f\n", i, f[i]
}'  "${d}_"*/input.csv > "${rescore}/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
```

Briefly, the workflow should process each line of the input.csv located inside ${d} folder that correctly has been identified by my bash script:

```
# input.csv located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 # this is dG(min)
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200
```

My AWK script is expected to process each line of each CSV file in order to reduce them to the two columns, keeping in the output: i) the number from the first column of the input.csv (contained ID of the processed line) + the name of the folder ($d) contained the CSV file as well as ii) the result of the math operation (f) applied on the numbers in POP and dG columns of the input.csv:

```
f(ID)= sqrt(((dG(ID)+10)/10)^2+((POP(ID)-240)/240))^2)
```

where dG(ID) is the value of dG ($3) of the "rescored" line of input.csv, and POP(ID) is its POP value ($2).Eventually output.csv contained information regarding 1 input.csv should be in the following format:

```
# output.csv
ID,             rescore value
1 10V1_cne_lig12,  f(ID1)
2 10V1_cne_lig12,  f(ID2)
3 10V1_cne_lig12,  f(ID3)
4 10V1_cne_lig12,  f(ID4)
```

While bash part of my code (dealing with the looping of CSVs in the distinct directories) works correctly I am stuck with the AWK code, which does not assign correctly ID of the lines in order that I could apply demonstrated math operations using $2 and $3 columns of the line with precised ID.

Comment: Where is "10V1_cne_lig12" coming from?

Comment: all folders (contained input.csv) are located inside $storage, which has been defined in bash part (and it works correctly!) Literally we are looping in bash many folders in $storage (each of each contain a three-column input.csv file) and then apply AWK code for each  csv.file

Comment: we don't know your data.  We only see what you post here.  Where are you planning to extract that string?  Is it a file name, one of the existing fields, needs to be derived from other fields, constant?

Comment: Actually it’s the name of the folder ( containing csv) that should be directly extracted and mentioned near ID of the first column ... but for the simplicity you may just write an example of AWK part only focusing on math equation, as it might be applied only on one csv file to process its second and third columns... many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the input file:  folder/file

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200
```

this script

```
$ awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
        FNR==1 {path=FILENAME; sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path); print $1,"rescore value"; next} 
               {print $1" "path, sqrt((($3+10)/10)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)}' folder/file
```

will produce

```
ID, rescore value
1 folder, 0.596625
2 folder, 1.05873
3 folder, 1.11285
4 folder, 0.697402
```

Not sure what the rest of your code does, but I guess you can integrate it in.

Comment: Yes, thank you! now AWK part works very well! One question - is it possible to pipe (in order that I could use it optionally to benchmark my data) you AWK sollution to something like sed that will further filter the output and reduce it to one line: keeping only the first column from the header (1st line) + the dG value from the line which contains its lowest value + its ID in the (). For our example the filtered output should be: ID, 0.596625 (1) .

Comment: just made a new topic demonstrating my bash/awk code for the clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67501145/awk-sed-post-processing-of-multi-column-filles