# awk/sed: post-processing of multi-column fille(s)

Tags: awk, sed

I am using the following bash function that operates on CSV files and execute for each AWK code doing some math operations on the column data and eventually saves the processed CSV in a new file.

```
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results_bench
cd "${storage}"
# pattern of the csv file located inside each of sub-directory of "${storage}"
str='*str1.csv'

rescore_data2 () {
str_name=$(basename "${str}" .csv)
printf >&2 'Dataset for %s is being rescored...  ' "${str_name}"; sleep 0.1 
mkdir "${rescore}"/"${str_name}"
# Apply the following AWK code for rescoring and final data collecting
while read -r d; do
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    FNR==1 {
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        print suffix,"dG(rescored)"
        next
    }
    {
        print $1, sqrt((($3+12)/12)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)
    }
'  "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/"${str_name}"/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
}
```

Basically each processed CSV has the following format:

```
#inout CSV located in the folder 10V1_cne_lig12
ID, POP, dG
1, 142, -5.6500 
2, 10, -5.5000
3, 2, -4.9500
4, 150, -4.1200
```

My awk code converts it to the 2 column format (via applying math equation on the 2nd and 3rd columns):

```
# output.csv
lig12, dG(rescored)
1, 0.596625
2, 1.05873
3, 1.11285
4, 0.697402
```

Note that lig12 in the first line is the **suffix** (used as the ID of the csv) extracted by my AWK code from the part of the FOLDER contained this CSV, and 10V1 is the **prefix** ( defines type of the csv)

I need to pipe my AWK script to something like sed or AWK that will do further modifications **of the obtained output.csv** , which should be converted to one line format, containing: the suffix (lig12), the minimal value detected in the second column of the output (here it is 0.596625) as well as its corresponded ID number  from the first column (1):

```
lig12, 0.596625 (1)
```

Here is one line AWK solution, which do the job just for one csv:

```
 awk -F ', ' ' NR==1 { coltitle=$1 } NR==2 { min=$2; id=$1 } NR>3 && $2<min { min=$2; id=$1 } END { print coltitle FS min" ("id")" }'
```

May it be piped correctly to the first AWK code inside of the rescore_data2(), which is applied on many CSVs processed by my bash function? So the expected output stored in ("${rescore}/"${str_name}"/"${d%%_*}".csv") should contain the number of the lines (with the dG(min) of each CSV) equal to the number of the processed CSVs.

```
# expected output for 10 processed CSVs belonged to the prefix 10V1
# currently it does not print dGmin correctly for different CSVs.
    name: 10V1, dG(min)     # header with prefix should be in the top!
    lig199, 0.946749 (1)
    lig211, 0.946749 (1)
    lig278, 0.756155 (2)
    lig40, 0.756155 (2)
    lig576, 0.594778 (1)
    lig619, 0.594778 (1)
    lig697, 0.594778 (1)
    lig800, 0.594778 (1)
    lig868, 0.594778 (1)
    lig868, 0.594778 (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have extracted awk script as follows (with minor modifications):

```
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    FNR==1 {
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        print suffix,"dG(rescored)"
        next
    }
    {
        print $1, sqrt((($3+12)/12)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)
    }
' 10V1_cne_lig12/foo_str3a.csv
```

The output looks like:

```
lig12, dG(rescored)
1, 0.668396
2, 1.10082
3, 1.15263
4, 0.756198
```

Although the values slightly *differ* from the provided result,
please let me go on as is.
Then add a modifications to the awk script as:

```
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    FNR==1 {
        dgmin = ""                              # initialize the min value
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        print suffix,"dG(rescored)"
        next
    }
    {
        dG = sqrt((($3+12)/12)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)
        if (dGmin == "" || dG < dGmin) {
            dGmin = dG                          # update the min dG value
            dGminid = $1                        # update the ID with the min dG
        }
    }
    END {
        print suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")"    # report the results
    }
' 10V1_cne_lig12/foo_str3a.csv
```

Output:

```
lig12, dG(rescored)
lig12, 0.668396 (1)
```

You'll see the 1st record is picked along with its ID.
The awk script above assumes the input file is just one.
If you want to process multiple csv files at once, you will need
to put the `"report the results"` line not only in the `END{}` block but
*possibly* the starting of the `FNR==1{}` block
(whenever one file processing is done).

**[Update]**
Would you replace your `rescore_data3()` function with:

```
rescore_data3 () {
str_name=$(basename "${str}" .csv)
printf >&2 'Dataset for %s is being rescored...  ' "${str_name}"; sleep 0.1
mkdir -p "${rescore}"/"${str_name}"
# Apply the following AWK code for rescoring and final data collecting
while read -r d; do
awk -F', *' -v OFS=', ' '
    FNR==1 {
        if (suffix)                             # suppress the empty line
            print suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")"
                                                # report the results
        dGmin = ""                              # initialize the min value
        path=FILENAME
        sub(/\/[^/]+$/,"",path)
        prefix=suffix=FILENAME
        sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
        sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
        if (FNR==NR)
            print prefix                        # print the header line
        next
    }
    {
        dG = sqrt((($3+12)/12)^2+(($2-240)/240)^2)
        if (dGmin == "" || dG < dGmin) {
            dGmin = dG                          # update the min dG value
            dGminid = $1                        # update the ID with the min dG
        }
    }
    END {
        print suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")"    # report the results
    }
' "${d}_"*/${str} > "${rescore}/"${str_name}"/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
}
```

- As mentioned before, you need to put a condition such as `if (suffix) ...`
  in the `FNR==1{}` block to suppress the empty line at the beginning of the result file.
- I'm sorry I made a typo as `dgmin = ""` which should be `dGmin = ""`
  in my previous answer.
- Better to put `-p` option to `mkdir` so you can avoid the
  `mkdir: cannot create directory: File exists` error.

Comment: OK thank you!!  Your first AWK script (reedition of the mine) works absolutely correctly and print the same numbers as mine. The second AWK script (which is looking for dG min) always print suffix,"dG(rescored)" correctly (althought I don't need this line in my final output) for a number of CSV files,  while working in the bash loop shown in my first post. However, it does not print the line with the dG(min), which is required (suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")" ), printing it  only for the LAST processed CSV fille..

Comment: ... now, as you suggested at the end of your reply, I put print suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")"    # report the results in the FNR==1 {} part of the AWK script. It prints now the info regarding all CSV (w/out the first one) submitted in once but all the values in rescored clumns are the same for different filles ...

Comment: It is not because the first csv is skipped but it adds an unnecessary
line just before the first csv is processed. In our previous project,
it was masked with the condition `if (n > 0) ...` or something like that.
Now we could do the similar thing with `if (suffix != "") print suffix, dGmin " (" dGminid ")"`. Anyway this is not an elegant solution and we better to
refactor the code including the interface between bash and awk.

Comment: m.b. it is easy just to pipe the first version of awk code( which works correctly in my bash engine) to something which will compute dGmin separately and further filter the data ?

Comment: Hmm.., it is possible but I don't think it helps to simplify the total set of codes because we need to parse the output of the previous process each time. In addition, once the file structure (number of fields, name of the items, etc.) is changed, we need to modify whole scripts. Let me consider how we can simplify the codes.

Comment: The other way like it has been done in a previous project (where AWK worked in the same bash routine), through the array that has been assosiated with suffix (which is used as the ID of each csv) to print dGmin[suffix] = dGmin etc >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67455916/awk-manipulations-with-multi-column-data

Comment: Anyway I can’t really understand why your first awk solution that write all IDs works Ok with multiple csvs send the second one which reduces number of the lines on each file , doesn’t work :-(

Comment: The mismatch may be because we edit the codes locally for each convenience. Can you provide your code as well as the csv files including the directory structure so I can reproduce your problem? It does not have to include whole files. Just a few csv files and your bash code embedding the awk will be a great help. BR.

Comment: No problem, I can put all into the same zip archive . How I can upload it there ?

Comment: Thank you. It wil be a great help. I'll leave the location to you wherever I have a permission to access and you can keep your required confidentiality. BR.

Comment: Will the google drive be ok ?? Should I simplify my bash script keeping only function where we have a pb ? And no confidiality at all since this is a mostly student  project !

Comment: Perfect. I was aldo thinking about google drive.

Comment: You do not have to take your time to simplify your code. The important thing is we can work with the same resource. BR.

Comment: It's high time now for me to sleep and my next reply will  be tomorrow. Bye now.

Comment: Ok , have a good night ! I shall post here the link with script and all required files ! Cheers

Comment: Briefly: for each of the folder located in results_bench it applies filter_csv()  to operate on *_proc.csv producing 4 additional csvs *str1.csv ... *str4.csv which shoud be processed using the rescore2() or rescore3(). Rescore2() works OK and rescore3() is one which should reduce number of the lines via computing dG(min), which we have discussed. I also put rescore() , as an example, from a previos project, which technically works OK in this bash workflow. A condition flow (on the line 393) alows to choose between rescore functions ( now it's rescore2())

Comment: Thank you for preparing the files. I have certainly downloaded the zip file. Would you allow me a day or two to feedback? BR.

Comment: Yes absolutely, no worries there ! Also I could find another awk solution which do  the job for one csv but does not work with all repertoire as well.. so the idea might be to find a possibility to pipe correctly the results of  rescoring2() to this awk one liner.  I am going to update my first topic with additional work information. Cheers

Comment: I've updated my answer with the modification of your `rescore_data3()` function. Tested with the provided files. BR.

Comment: Amazing, it looks very elegant. Thank you very much! let me ask just two short remarks  (for educational purposes): 1) may I use printf "%s %.3f (%d)\n", suffix, dGmin, dGminid in both # report result sections instead of print ? 2) In order to print dG(max) in the similar way, I introduced second condition, (having devined dGmax in FNR==1): if (dGmax == "" || dG > dGmax) {  dGmax = dG              dGmaxid = $1 }. is this syntax correct ?

Comment: Thank you for testing my answer. Good to know it's working. The answers to your remarks are: 1) Yes, you can. It will be more readable than `print`. 2) Absolutely. The advantage is you do not have to care the range of possible values compared to initialize the variable to 0. Please remember to reset the variable to "" on the initialization (possibly in the FNR==1{} block).

Comment: Right, thank you! regarding ii) i was interested mostly if I need 2 separate IF conditions for dGmin and dGmax (like I've done) or put it into the one, which has being used for dGmin...  However, my version works fine... BTW based on this one more project has came into my mind: I swear this shall be the last one since the informatics professor will be going on health leave in two weeks! BUT I will sleep peacefully if I find out the TRUTH

Comment: Answering your question, you need to have separate IF conditions to find minimum and maximum values respectively. Cheers.

Comment: Right, like I've done so.. Anyway, the final episode will be there >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67546725/awk-math-operations-on-a-number-of-data-filles-using-flexible-variables           and I belive that if the solution exists, we shall recieve the Noble prize in AWK